# A general expansion $\prod_{j=1}^{k}(1+x^j+x^{2j}+x^{3j}+x^{4j})$.

Tags: combinatorics

Can we get a formula for a certain coefficient from the general expansion $$\prod_{j=1}^{k}(1+x^j+x^{2j}+x^{3j}+x^{4j})?$$ I tried to observe the coefficients using Wolfram's Mathematica, but could not figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of $x^n$ is the number of ways to write 
$n = m_1 + 2 m_2 \ldots + k m_k$ where each $m_j \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.
If $n \le k$ it is [OEIS sequence A035959](https://oeis.org/A035959).